# Setting the height of a Form in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-3.5

My CSS doesn't work so well when using it in ASP.Net it appear to use the background image only when there's actual content inside of the form. (It dynamically grows vertically).

Is there a way for me to specify the height of my ASP.Net form?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:inherit">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<div class="Content">        
    <img src="../../Images/Logo.png" alt="Logo MiCompra" />
    <H1>Bienvenidos a MiCompra!</H1>
        <p>Bienvenidos a MiCompra. Compre lo que quiera, cuando quiera.</p>
        <p>Bienvenidos a MiCompra. Compre lo que quiera, cuando quiera.</p> 
</div>
</form>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a pic of what it looks like when it is displayed and what you want it to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the height of the div.